# How do I eliminate read and connection timeouts to my REST Service?

Tags: java, rest, jetty, jersey-client

I have a Java REST service which I built using Jetty. The DB is SQL Server.
My clients are getting a lot of connection and read timeouts. I would like to ask your help on what do I do to eliminate those timeouts?

I have 6 load balanced servers with the following specs:
8 core Xeon CPU and
16 GB RAM.

The timeouts occur when requests peak at 10,000/sec but they just happen from time to time. Caching is not really an option at the moment.

I've talked with the clients and they've set the requests to 1500ms and they don't want to increase that number. They are using jersey aync for the client library.

Any ideas on how we can solve this? Thank you  in advance!

P.S.
I've ran this in staging and in the same network and I'm getting timeouts still. 
I'm trying to solve the client timeouts. thanks!

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the nature of those timeouts.  Connection and Read Timeouts can be the result of dozens of factors, which ones specifically are you attempting to resolve and on what side? (Server or Client?) - and no, its not possible to eliminate all kinds of network timeouts forever (but you can get as close to your line of diminishing return as you are comfortable)

Comment: Hi @JoakimErdfelt I'm trying to solve client timeouts. I've ran tests in staging and I was getting read and connection timeouts whenever I increase the concurrent connections to 2000. What do you think is the 3 best thing that I should do to lessen them?

Comment: 1500mS is an incredibly aggressive timeout for a network operation. It should be of the order of ten seconds.

Comment: @EJP Tell me about it. Anyway do you think there are solutions that I can do to help this?